# Objective-C: taking index of object in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, logging, indexing

I'm new in Obj C programming, so i will start from beginning
I have an array with some NSNumber and NSString elements, i want to replace NSString elems to NSNumber elems. I decide to make this with for in construction get to new NSMutableArray all elements value and to NSMutableIndexSet their indexes, but when i made this i faced with trouble, here it is, i show you my code and log.

```
NSArray *oneMoreStack = [program copy];
NSLog(@" stack=%@",oneMoreStack);
NSLog(@" show me index ind=%@",[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:@"x"]);
NSMutableIndexSet *myVarIndexesSet;
NSMutableArray *myVarsArray;


for (id myVarConst in oneMoreStack) {
    if([myVarConst isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if([myVarConst isEqualToString:@"x"]){
            [myVarsArray addObject:myVarConst];
            NSLog(@"obj x=%@",myVarConst);
            [myVarIndexesSet addIndex:[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:myVarConst]];
            NSLog(@"ind x=%@",[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:myVarConst]);

        } 
}
```

When i run it log show me this:

```
Calculator[6306:f803]  stack=(
    x,
    2,
    "+"
)
Calculator[6306:f803]  show me index ind=(null)
Calculator[6306:f803] obj x=x
Calculator[6306:f803] ind x=(null)
then crash [NSMutableArray replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:]: index set cannot be nil
```

So, my question is why does **`[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:myVarConst]`** return **`null`**? How can i fix it? Thanks.
I don't mention this code before because think problem is in getting indexes.

after previous part of code goes this part:

```
[stack replaceObjectsAtIndexes:[myVarIndexesSet copy] withObjects:[myVarsArray copy]];
```

after that crash with error report i mention previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:myVarConst]` returns an NSUInteger, a primitive type, not an object.

In your NSLog, you are using %@, which says "Hey, take this object I'm passing as an argument, call `-description` on it, and print it out".  Luckily, the NSUInteger you are passing in happens to be 0,  NSLog thinks that it is a null object, and you aren't crashing.  If the call to -indexOfObject: returns non-0, you will likely crash.

Try this instead:

```
// For iOS
NSLog(@" show me index ind=%u", [oneMoreStack indexOfObject:@"x"]);
```

or

```
// For 64-bit and 32-bit Mac OS X
NSLog(@" show me index ind=%lu", (unsigned long)[oneMoreStack indexOfObject:@"x"]);
```

You can learn more about string formats at:
[Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Comment: yes, i don't think about it, now log show me the index, but there is appear another question, if all fine with indexes why the error message in log is ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:]: index set cannot be nil` i made something wrong when add index to index set?? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the mention of the crash.  Can you update your qustion with the code where you call -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:], -[NSMutableArray replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:], or -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes:]?  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you never initialized myVarIndexesSet to an actual object: `NSMutableIndexSet *myVarIndexesSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];`.  If you are compiling under ARC, what you currently have will set myVarIndexesSet to nil.  If you are in non-ARC mode, myVarIndexesSet will be an unknown value since it isn't initialized, and you could crash the first time you try to message it.

Comment: oh great thanks, now i'm catch where alloc init is need i think :) thanks, that is just what i need.